# Python - How to add parametric line from data on top of contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have some problems trying to fit together two different plots. On the one hand, I have a contour plot [image: ContourPlot]

On the other hand, I have a 1D plot [image: LinePlot]

My goal is to basically get a path on top of the contour following the values from the line plot. Physically, the not all variables from the contour plot are available. For example, at a0=0 I would start at point (0,0) and then I would get a path to (0.5,1.6) for a0=0.8.

Problem is I don't fully know how to combine both data. Here is the code for the contour:

```
r_field=np.linspace(0,2.0,21)   ##squeezed bath
n_field=np.linspace(0,0.5,21)  ## thermal bath
n_index=0
for Nth in n_field:
    r_index=0
    for r in r_field:
        N = Nth * (np.cosh(r)**2 + np.sinh(r)**2) + np.sinh(r)**2
        M =np.cosh(r) * np.sinh(r) * np.exp(-1j * theta) * (2 * Nth + 1)
        L=(N+1)*L1+(N+1)*L2+N*L1_d+N*L2_d+M*(Lm+Lm_d)
        msol=solve_ivp(Master, [min(t_span),max(t_span)] , rho_in , t_eval= t_span)
        #purity_field[r_index,n_index]=np.real(msol.y[:,-1].reshape(4,4).dot(msol.y[:,-1].reshape(4,4)).trace())
        concurrence_field[r_index,n_index]=Concurrence(msol.y[:,-1])
        r_index+=1
    print(n_index)    
    n_index+=1
xlist = r_field
ylist = n_field
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
Z = concurrence_field.transpose()
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z,levels=np.linspace(0.0,np.max(concurrence_field),19),cmap='coolwarm')
fig.colorbar(cp) 
ax.set_title(r'Concurrence two qubits in a squeezed thermal reservoir at $\gamma=%s$'% (gamma1))
ax.set_xlabel(r'$r_{sq}$', fontsize='20')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$n_{th}$', fontsize='20')
plt.show()
```

and for the line plot

```
a_0_list=np.linspace(0.0,0.8,100)
eta=0.1

rsq_fp=np.zeros(len(a_0_list),dtype=np.float64)
nth_fp=np.zeros(len(a_0_list),dtype=np.float64)

i=0
for a_0 in a_0_list:
    nth_fp[i]=4*np.sqrt(det(eta,a_0))-1/2
    rsq_fp[i]=np.arctanh(X1X2(eta,a_0)/XX(eta,a_0))/2.0
    i+=1
plt.plot(a_0_list,nth_fp,label=r'$n_{th}$')
plt.plot(a_0_list,rsq_fp,label=r'$r_{sq}$')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(fontsize='15')
plt.xlabel(r'$<a_{0}>$',fontsize='20')
plt.show();
```

where I have skipped a few unnecessary lines of code.

A bit of guidance would be appreciated. It would also be great if I could label some discrete points along the path, placing the corresponding a0 value.
Thanks,

Comment: Probably you can just use `ax.plot(rsq_fp, nth_fp, color='gold')` on the `ax` of the first plot.